# Using PHP to compare images, not using file date/size

Tags: php, image

I'm attempting to utilize PHP to compare 2 separate images which may or may not contain the same image.  Essentially, they are from an item database application and would have been saved over a year apart.  The images are usually resized from roughly 600x600 to 300x300 and in one I checked by eye the image was the same but the file size varied by about 8kb.

Example, 
Image created 1/25/2012 is 7,102 bytes
Image created 2/1/2014  is 7,094 bytes

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Naive and simple method: Iterate over all pixels and check if their colour is the same

Comment: When you resave a lossy-compressed image, it's no longer the same as the original if you go pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mncaudill/1326966) is a quick and easy way of comparing two images in PHP, based on [this blog post](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html).

Tweak the size of `$new_img` and whether to use grayscaling or not, and find that sweet spot that works on the data you have. When implementing this you should manually check the results a (preferably large) dataset to find out what works best for you.